# Bootstrap 3: How to make a centered navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've seen some hacks for Bootstrap <=2 but I'm using v3 and I want to make a horizontal row of links that are centered within the row/container. Here's my markup:

```
<div class="footer row">    
    <div class="col-12">                
        <ul id="menu-main" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="text-center">
                <%= link_to "Home", root_path  %>
            </li>
            <li class="text-center">
                <%= link_to "About", root_path  %>          
            </li>
            <li class="text-center">
                <%= link_to "Help", root_path  %>           
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Have you seen the documentation under Grid System > Nesting Columns http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Check out the bootstrap 3 examples. [This sounds like what you are looking for.](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/)

Comment: @Schmalzy Justified nav is cool, but I don't want to fan out the links across the page. I only have a few so I want them just center with normal spacing.

Comment: @Emerson check out my [personal website](http://brandonschmalz.com). Is the top-navbar what you are looking for? If so, feel free to steal the code. It was created using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: @Schmalzy Yup. That's the idea. However, I'd like to have the option to collapse into vertical rows on small screens. Yours is only three so you don't need it but mine probably will.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This should be exactly what you are looking for.

[Here is a jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/mVXYR/4/)

If you want this as a fixed-footer, just add `navbar-fixed-bottom` class to the `<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">` element.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
   </div>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav{
        float:none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ruben Are you using `Respond.js`? it is required for media queries in IE8 and IE9 See [the Bootstrap Browser Support Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers) for more info on this.

Comment: @danza `table-layout: fixed` is not required, it only helps the browser generate the table slightly faster.

Comment: Works in Chrome

Answer (score 6):

```css
.nav.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
#menu-main{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display:block;
}
#menu-main li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#menu-main a{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="footer row">    
    <div class="col-12">                
        <ul id="menu-main" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Help</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Adam's suggestion, I see that this basically works:

```
    <div class="footer row">    

            <ul id="menu-main" class="list-inline text-center">
                <li class="text-center">
                    <%= link_to "Home", root_path  %>
                </li>
                <li class="text-center">
                    <%= link_to "About", root_path  %>          
                </li>
                <li class="text-center">
                    <%= link_to "Help", root_path  %>           
                </li>
                <li class="text-center">
                    <%= mail_to "e@streetofwalls.com", "Contact"   %>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

However, it won't collapse on smaller widths like a navbar. It would be nice to maintain this functionality if someone knows how.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to give the navbar a side margin of 25%:

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .centered-ul{
    margin-left:25%;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav centered-ul">
...
</ul>
```