# Centering the Navigation Bar and its Elements in HTML

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar, centering

I am having problems creating a centred navigation bar where the child elements are also centred. I used nav-justified which almost works but then that seems to break the model so that when the window is smaller the collapsed menu stops working properly.

Html code is:

```
        <header id="header">
        <div class="container">

            <!-- MOBILE MENU -->
            <button id="mobileMenu" class="fa fa-bars" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse"></button>

            <!-- NAV MENU -->
            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
                <ul id="onepageNav" class="nav  nav-justified"><!-- id="onepageNav" for homepage only -->
                        <li class="active"><a href="#how">How</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#support">Support</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#consultancy">Consultancy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- /NAV MENU -->

        </div>
    </header>
```

Not sure what css to include so will add whatever you need to see.

There are a few questions on this already out there but the answers don't seem to work for me.

Really very grateful for any help and explanations as I am quite new to this.

Thank you

Comment: From your class names it looks like you are using Bootstrap, if so see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535441/bootstrap-3-how-to-make-a-centered-navbar/18538412#18538412

Comment: thank you for replying - will also try this.  I did look at this before but couldn't get it to work...will have another go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them to have space between them, you're dealing with a common problem. Here's a good resource: http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/

However, if you just want them simply arranged centered

```css
nav { text-align: center; }

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}  

nav ul li { 
  display: inline-block; 
  background: pink;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
                <ul id="onepageNav" class="nav  nav-justified"><!-- id="onepageNav" for homepage only -->
                        <li class="active"><a href="#how">How</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#support">Support</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#consultancy">Consultancy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Fantastic - that seems to work on a full screen.  Can you advise me how to get the same effect as the window size shrinks?

Comment: When I resize, it just breaks line but everything stays centered. What behavior would you like to see?

Comment: when I shrink it the left hand side stays spaced from the margin but the right hand side of the menu ie Blog is up against the edge of the window.

Comment: Does it do that when you click the "Full Page" button in the snippet? It might be just an issue of the snippet frame.