# how do i align navabar in center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how to align bootstrap navbar in center of the page.
Below is my code and i want it to be aligned in center. i tried several things but not working. Can you please help me with this.

```
<nav class="navbar header-navbar hidden-xs" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li><a href="index.html" class="active-link">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                        <li><div class="cart-area"><a href="cart.html">Cart: 0</a></div></li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
```

Comment: Do you have any fiddle for this? Why dont you make [one](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Show us your CSS too.

Comment: Can you mention the things you tried ? so that, others don't answer with what you tried already.

Comment: Atleast post some of your css. So that we try where its going wrong.

Comment: have you tried to give the `<nav>` a width and add `margin:0 auto;`?

Comment: .navbar-nav > li > a
{
 color: #fff;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover
{
 background-color: #000;
 color: #5BE7F7;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a.active-link
{
 color: #5BE7F7;
}

Comment: Yes Paul, i have tried the same

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3: How to make a centered navbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535441/bootstrap-3-how-to-make-a-centered-navbar)

Answer (score 1):

Someone else posted the solution to a similar question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535441/bootstrap-3-how-to-make-a-centered-navbar)

shoud work:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav{
        float:none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
}
```

Comment: In such cases, you should flag the question as duplicate instead of copying answers over.

Comment: you can remove the "min-width" property, or change its value

Comment: @Xan ok, sorry! I'm a noob on stackoverflow :-)