# Unable to center <ul> inside column in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want a navbar like this:

[image: Navbar hoped]

It seems that my idea of putting row and columns inside the navbar is a wrong idea, but it kind of works…

Now, I would like my navigation links (the `<ul>`) to be centered across the page, and I tried a lot of thing but here's what I can only get:

[image: Navbar having]

The “/” separators does not make it easier…

**HTML**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="<?php echo $site->url() ?>"><img alt="Logo" class="navbar-left navbar-brand-logo" src="<?php echo url('assets/images/logo.png') ?>" style="height: 50px;">
                    <span class="navbar-brand" style="color: white;">GilDev</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
                    <li class="separator hidden-xs">/</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projets</a></li>
                    <li class="separator hidden-xs">/</li>
                    <li><a href="#">À propos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Ubuntu;
    src: url("../fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf");
}

body, a
{
    color: white;
}

.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: white;
}

body
{
    background-image: url("../images/gradient.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: #64B2DF;
    font-family: Ubuntu, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.separator
{
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.navbar-brand-logo
{
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.navbar
{
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

First time I try to make my own theme with Bootstrap, and I suck… Hope you have ideas to center these links! Thanks!

Comment: It's actually very easy to achieve this @GilDev. Check out my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38536836/6313073

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3: How to make a centered navbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535441/bootstrap-3-how-to-make-a-centered-navbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can easily have the menu you want** by using the following code on **`.nav`**:

```
.nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Check out [this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9h4ospvs/) for a visual representation.

Comment: Works but make the links stack up when reducing window width, although the column seems to be large enough…

Comment: @GilDev this would happen anyway them being centered or not. You can use **`@media`** queries to make them adapt to different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
ul.nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.nav > li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```